Save results from Jmeter to SQL Server database
In Jmeter.
Does anyone know how to save all results from a test and store them in SQL Server?
Is it possible to store the results directly in SQL Server, or do I need to load them via a CSV file?
I have tried using JSR223, but I couldn't get it to work with my CSV file.

The best would be using BULK INSERT command, you will need to copy JMeter's .jtl results file to the machine where the SQL server is running somehow, create the table and import the file like:
FROM '/path/to/result.jtl'
WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    FIRSTROW = 1
)

it can be done even with JDBC Request sampler somewhere in tearDown Thread Group:

In the realtime it can be done using i.e. JDBC PostProcessor but this way it may negatively impact your test throughput
Also your "couldn't get it to work" statement doesn't tell much to us, you need to show at least partial code and explain what is the anticipated result and what is the error you're getting. See Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For? article to learn more about Groovy scripting in JMeter context.

I am generating the csv with summary report and uploading it with JSR223. If I close the test and on run only the upload part it works. I think the problem is that summary reports keeps the csv open. I have tried with timers and splitting the test into 2 tread groups and still it looks like is not released by the summary report.

Also i run the tread groups consecutively
